# fireEvent for PointerEvent only receives Event minus my set options

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to send a `PointerEvent` to my code for testing. This is a `pointerDown` but I've seen the same problem with `pointerMove` as well as `pointerUp`

```
// Fake primary mouse down input
    fireEvent.pointerDown(domElement, {
      button: MouseButton.Primary,
      clientX: 5,
      clientY: 5,
    });
```

When I receive the event to my handler `event.button`, `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` are all undefined.

I confirmed that using this the same way for a `WheelEvent` works as expected.

Am I doing something wrong in this instance specifically?

Comment: Please show the component code.

Comment: So the component is just a div. In the test I just need the event to be created and fired from the div such as `const domElement = document.createElement('div');`

Comment: Here is an example that has a test that shows the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fireevent-pointerevent-problem-6de1d?file=/tst/HandlesPointerEvents.spec.ts

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you are testing in a JSDOM environment, the problem here is that JSDOM does not, at time of writing, support setting the event properties when creating pointer events. See [this testing library issue](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/558) and [this JSDOM PR which should resolve the issue but can't yet be merged](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/2666). A workaround is suggested in the testing library issue.